# IBM Worklight - Can we create a desktop based application?

Tags: desktop-application, ibm-mobilefirst

Can we create a Desktop application using Worklight?

For example, we can create a desktop based applications using Adobe AIR, Titanium, RCP, etc.
What such type of applications can we develop using Worklight?

Answer (score 3):

If you click on Worklight icon, you can create a Worklight environment associated to your worklight project.
This is an example on Worklight 5.0.6

[image]
[image]

Other information [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_setting_up_new_wl_environment.html)

Comment: I simply wrote the procedure

Answer (score 1):

In **Worklight 6.0.0** you can create a Worklight app that will run on:

- Windows 8 (hybrid desktop / tablet)
- Adobe Air
- Destkop browsers (by embedding in an  HTML page)

In **Worklight 5.0.6** you can create a Worklight app that will run on:

- Windows 8 (hybrid desktop / tablet)
- Adobe Air
- Embedded (renamed to "Desktop Browser" in 6.0)
- Windows 7 Gadgets (deprecated, removed in 6.0)
- OS X Dashboard (deprecated, removed in 6.0)