# Worklight Security Tests usage in External Application(WAR) deployed in Liberty Profile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Have a question can we use the security tests in a external application(war) that gets deployed in Websphere liberty profile server. if yes then how to configure the same. The security test will be independent to worklight application and that of the external application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you talking about? Your scenario is not clear to me.

Worklight security tests are meant to be configured in the Worklight project's authenticationConfig.xml and to then be used to protect adapter procedures in the adapter XML file and/or applications in application-descriptor.xml; they are not meant to be used in any other context.

Comment: To be more clear. correct me if i'm wrong can we develop an entire web application in worklight ? this is requirement for us to develop everything in worklight including a web app

Comment: when you say "web app", do you mean Mobile Web, or Android, iPhone, etc...? Please be exact.

Comment: "Web App" means app on desktop browser

Comment: So that's the Desktop Browser environment.

Comment: Can we develop that as a web browser as a ref from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709490/ibm-worklight-can-we-create-a-desktop-based-application.Complete full fledged Web application with (DB transactions,HTML pages, Business logic layer) basically a 3- Tier architecture application on worklight

Comment: Can we do a Spring application then ?

Comment: What does that have to do with the environments you can create in Worklight Studio? I don't see "spring application", so... no.

Comment: When we develop spring project in general we bring in its capabilities with jars and configurations ..just trying to understand if we can do the same in worklight project as well

Comment: You can create in Worklight what is documented that you can create with Worklight; Please read the user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A/welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
I believe you want to protect your Worklight console (war) with security test and it is possible. you can protect your console with username and password. ( possible to use plain text or encrypted). For more info see [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html)

to enable security test you need to edit your `authenticationConfig.xml` with the following code.

```
    <staticResources>
        <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
            <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
         </resource>  

    </staticResources> 


<securityTests>
<customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
            <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest> 
</securityTests>
<realms>
<realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="WorklightConsole">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
        </realm>
</realms>

<loginModules>
<loginModule name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
</loginModules>
```