# IBM Worklight Standalone Desktop Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, desktop-application

Is it possible to create a Windows 7 standalone desktop application for Worklight Project? I know that Worklight uses Adobe Air for the desktop framework, but is there any other solutions for desktop rather than Air?

Thanks

P.S : I've looked through other framework such as Node-webkit, Appjs, tideSdk but I wasn't sure that those frameworks can be implemented with worklight.
I also have read the related post but it doesn't answer my question.

[IBM Worklight - Can we create a desktop based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709490/ibm-worklight-can-we-create-a-desktop-based-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Windows  7 "widgets" has been removed from Worklight starting Worklight 6.1.

The only remaining desktop-supporting environment is Adobe Air.